# What's wrong with this SQL command?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a problem with a SQL Command.

I have a string that holds a SQL command, but when I run, it returns me an error: Column n1 does not exist Note: n1 is what I typed in my textField.

Code:

```
String nameprod tf_NameProd.getText = ();
         String sql = "select * from Product where prod_name =" + nameprod;//<-- this is my query
         iaeprod.Table(sql, tbl_Prod);
```

Any idea where I am missing?

Comment: You are missing the quotes.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` - [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer This doesn't seem to be JDBC, so it's hard to tell whether that advice would work.

Comment: @MatheusCirillo Note: someone could type `' or '' = '` to see all products, or they could type something much longer and more complicated to *run commands on your computer* - if this matters to you, then you should probably be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put single quotes around the string in your SQL. For example in your case it should be

```
"select * from Product where prod_name = '" + nameprod + "'";
```

Comment: Great! Fixed! You was the first who answered, so I'll mark your answear as solution in 5 minutes (when they release me). Thanks so much!

Comment: @MatheusCirillo If you can vote please upvote the others as well, i guess the few seconds i was faster should not be a bummer for the other guys, but none the less: you´re welcome :)

Comment: @Abbel Check out the "help" link when you answer to see other options for formatting. Happy Answering on SO!

Answer (score 2):

```
String sql = "select * from Product where prod_name = '" + nameprod + "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

because `prod_name` is a `String` use single quotes around the value

```
 String sql = "select * from Product where prod_name ='" + nameprod+"'";
```

it will better to use prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

Use this method instead:

```
Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection();

PreparedStatement stmt = null;

String nameProd = "select * from Product where prod_name =  ?";

stmt = connection.prepareStatement(nameProd);
stmt.setString(1, tf_NameProd.getText() );

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

P.S.: I haven't compiled this code. Please put try and catch statements at appropriate places